# Linear transformation explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I have the following exercise:

> Consider the [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) L: ℝ³→ ℝ². Knowing that:
>
> $$ L \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} =
> \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} \space\space\space\space\space\space
> L \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} =
> \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \space\space\space\space\space\space
> L \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} =
> \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix} $$ determine the following: $$ L
> \begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\2\end{pmatrix} =  \space\space  ?
> $$

Can someone explain how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\\2 \end{pmatrix} = 2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} + 1\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So:
$$L\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\\2 \end{pmatrix} = L \left(2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} + 1\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} \right) = 2L\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} + L\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} + L\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix}$$